# How to force spring (boot) to use ehcahe 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ehcache

I have spring-boot application with hazelcast integration.
Now I need to add also ehcache support. `@EnableCaching` creates Hazelcast CacheManager. My gol is to use `@Cachable` with ehcache 3.

I've tried to manually define Ehcache CacheManager

```
  @Bean
  public CacheManager ehcache() {
    CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder().build();
    cacheManager.init();
    return cacheManager;
  }
```

but I've got:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'ehcache' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager' but was actually of type 'org.ehcache.core.EhcacheManager'.
```

Comment: You can check the example http://www.ehcache.org/blog/2016/05/18/ehcache3_jsr107_spring.html

Comment: At point 6 it says about @EnableCaching and for me it's creating hazelcast CacheManager instance not ehcache one.

Answer (score 2):

For Ehcache 3, you have to use `JCacheCacheManager` to wrap the Ehcache `CacheManager` and convert it into a Spring `CacheManager`. An exemple is available [here](https://imhoratiu.wordpress.com/2017/01/26/spring-4-with-ehcache-3-how-to/).

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder().build(true);
    JCacheCacheManager jCacheCacheManager = new JCacheCacheManager(cacheManager);
    return jCacheCacheManager;
 }
```

Comment: EhCacheManagerFactoryBean is factory bean for ehcache 2.x